# What is proper way to copy trusted host patterns from one Request to another?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony 2.6 application, and have a scenario where I need to copy the trusted host patterns from one [`Request`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object to another.

[`Request::setTrustedHosts`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_setTrustedHosts) accepts an array of regular expressions w/o the delimiters, and then the method creates proper PCRE patterns with delimiters, and saves them to a private property,

[`Request::getTrustedHosts`](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getTrustedHosts) returns the array of trusted host patterns w/ the delimiters.

What is the proper way to copy trusted host patterns from one request object to another?

```
$request2->setTrustedHosts($request1->getTrustedHosts());
```

doesn't work because of the delimiter differences.  Is the only way to something like

```
$hostPatterns = $request1->getTrustedHosts();
$hostPatterns = array_map(function ($hostPattern) {
  return substr($hostPattern, 1, -2);
}, $hostPatterns);
$request2->setTrustedHosts($hostPatterns);
```

I would like to avoid this, as it depends on the internal implementation and isn't programming against an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTrustedHosts` and `setTrustedHosts` set a static variable [`Request::$trustedHostPatterns`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/v2.6.1/Request.php#L54), therefore you shouldn't need to copy the hosts between objects as its [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and the same across all request objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 6/9 : RUN pip install —-trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 4c2c658a532c
Invalid requirement: '—-trusted-host'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'\xe2\x80\x94-trus'"
```

I was getting this error on my mac, and I resolved it by removing `—-trusted-host` from the run command.

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```